# JNI calling a C function calling an other function in an other file

Tags: java, c, function, java-native-interface, external

I have a problem calling a C function using an other C function from an other .c file from my Java JNI (don't mind some french words in my code, thank you). The code in C works fine.

Here are the two lines I use to compile my libraries. I am compiling my first library with the function that I use in my second library. Tell me if I am doing it wrong to be able to do this :

`gcc -fPIC -shared -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" -o Libraries/libfilemot.so ../IndexationTexte/fileMot.c
gcc -fPIC -shared -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" ../IndexationTexte/indexationV1.c -L./Libraries/ -l:libfilemot.so -o Libraries/libindexation.so`

In my Java class, I have this :

```
public class MoteurDeRecherche {

static {
    try {
        System.load("/home/aurelien/Documents/Projects/Projet_fil_rouge/noyau_c/JNI/Libraries/libfilemot.so");
        System.load("/home/aurelien/Documents/Projects/Projet_fil_rouge/noyau_c/JNI/Libraries/libindexation.so");
    }
    catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.out.println("Erreur de chargement des librairies :\n" + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static native void indexationTexte();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MoteurDeRecherche.indexationTexte();
}
```

}

But I get this error coming from my library that compiles successfully :

```
Erreur de chargement des librairies :
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/aurelien/Documents/Projects/Projet_fil_rouge/noyau_c/JNI/Libraries/libindexation.so: libfilemot.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Don't hesitate if you want more information. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found why, this is not the way to use multiple functions from multiple files. You simply have to put all of the files you need in the gcc command. I don't know why I tried to make a library for one file dependent from an other library for an other file. Here is the command for my project :

`gcc -fPIC -shared -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" ../IndexationTexte/indexationV1.c ../IndexationTexte/fileMot.c -o Libraries/libindexation.so`

For a more generic approach, if you have :

file1.c :

```
#include "file2.c"
void function1()
{
    function2();
}
```

file2.c :

```
void function2()
{
    printf("hey from an other file");
}
```

You have to simply compile your project like this :

`gcc -fPIC -shared -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" file1.C file2.c -o libmylibrary.so`

Comment: Usually, **I** would define a `file1.o` and a `file2.o` build target, then a linker target `mylib.so` that depends on those two object files - but yes, you need to tell the linker about both object files (or both source files).... see also `gcc -c`(*Only run preprocess, compile, and assemble steps*) (you still need pic and shared).

Answer (score 1):

The native linker can't find your shared object. Add the folder with your so to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:Libraries/
```

Alternatively, you can add that to your local libraries folder (usually `/usr/local/lib`) and rerun `ldconfig`.

Comment: +1, maybe you can suggest to check with `ldd /home/aurelien/Documents/Projects/Projet_fil_rouge/noyau_c/JNI/Libraries/libindexation.so` (if it's available on OP's platform)

Comment: I tried both ways and I still get this error, just to mention a few things : I am using Ubuntu 18.10 and Intellij, the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH was empty (I don't know if its normal) and when I added my .so files in /usr/local/lib/ I got a big JRE error when launching the Java program. I'm not really sure if I am doing this the right way to call a C function calling an other C function from an other file in Java.